# Spotify API unsupported_grant_type

Tags: perl, http, oauth, spotify

I'm using the [client credentials flow](https://beta.developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/#client-credentials-flow) for authentication to the Spotify API. I have everything I need set as it should be, but I still get the following error whenever I send the rquest.

```
400 Bad Request: {"error":"unsupported_grant_type","error_description":"grant_type must be client_credentials, authorization_code or refresh_token"}
```

Pertinent code is the following:

```
sub get_spotify_token{
    my $data={grant_type => "client_credentials"};

    my $req=HTTP::Request->new("POST",AUTH_TOKEN_URL,[
        "Content-Type" => "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "Authorization" => "Basic $ENV{SPOTIFY_CLIENT_B64}",
    ],encode_utf8 encode_json $data);

    # send request
    my $res=$ua->request($req);

    # return token or die on error
    if($res->is_success){
        return %{decode_json $res->content}{"access_token"};
    }else{
        die $res->status_line.": ".$res->content."\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) `encode_json` already encode using UTF-8, so `encode_utf8` shouldn't be there.

Comment: 2) You claim the content is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, but you provide JSON. What does the API actually expect?

Comment: @ikegami I tried omitting `encode_utf8` and got the same result. The API expects `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, but if I try to pass a plain hash to `HTTP::Request::new` I get an error complaining that it's a non-scalar reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The API expects `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` (`grant_type=client_credentials`) as you claim you provide, but you're providing JSON (`{"grant_type":"client_credentials"}`).

[HTTP::Request::Common](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTTP::Request::Common)'s `POST` makes it easy to build a `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` response.

```
use HTTP::Request::Common qw( POST );

my $req = POST(AUTH_TOKEN_URL,
    [
        grant_type => "client_credentials",
    ],
    Authorization => "Basic $ENV{SPOTIFY_CLIENT_B64}",
    Content_Type  => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
);
```

or

```
use HTTP::Request::Common qw( POST );

my $req = POST(AUTH_TOKEN_URL,
    Authorization => "Basic $ENV{SPOTIFY_CLIENT_B64}",
    Content_Type  => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    Content => [
        grant_type => "client_credentials",
    ],
);
```

Comment: I wasn't aware that I could pass `Content` as a header, thanks. Marked as accepted.

Comment: Fixed a bug. /// I prefer to use `Content` since it allows me to put the data "in order", but there's an alternate calling convention that doesn't make it look like a header. I've added it to the answer so you can choose the one you prefer.